# How do externalities work in runtime?

Tags: substrateinterface

What makes me confused about the runtime is the Externalities. I found the definition in `sp_externalities`, moreover I found that the `pub fn set_and_run_with_externalities(ext: &mut dyn Externalities, f: F)` function will supply an approach to work with the externalities mutable reference. So like the `TextExternalities` which makes us run some runtime code in a test environment. And the global variables `environmental::environmental!(ext: trait Externalities);` supplies the Externalities register on Substrate.

Due to the explanation above, I can write the following code:

```rust
TestExternalities.execute_with(||{
     Balances::deposit_creating(&ALICE, 100_000_000);
});
```

My question is that whether the pallet like balances will be handled by the pallet macros, and auto carry the reference named `ext`? Or at somewhere the substrate client side code could call the `sp_externalities::set_and_run_with_externalities(&mut some_ext, ||{ // really code })` .

In short, I want to know if there are some methods to add my new runtime interface or externalities into the runtime that replaces some behaviors of the substrate native storage implementation

Comment: I think you need to be more specific here. Not sure what you mean by "some methods to add my new runtime interface or externalities into the runtime". Generally modifying the storage behavior of your Substrate chain will make your node incompatible with Polkadot.

Comment: In other words, my question is that how pallet macros actual job, I have found the code in client side. When substrate receive a new block then will construct a new state machine from sp_state_machine and work with current block changes set. But I cant found that where the pallet storage items use the ext refernce at all

Comment: I'm sorry. Your question does not make sense to me. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask